# Why doesn't the auxiliary will qualify as future tense?

Tags: grammar, tenses, modal-verbs

According to *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, *Tense* is defined as follows:

> **Tense**. A system marked by verb **inflection** or **auxiliaries** whose basic use to locate the situation in time: I *liked* it (past tense, past time), I *like* it(present tense, present time).

However, the author also points out:

> ..., English is not one of them: **it has no future tense**. It does have several ways of talking about future time, and the most basic one does involve the auxiliary **will**.

These two quotes made me puzzled because, as noted above, *Tense* is denoted by inflection or auxiliaries and the auxiliary **will** seems to **clearly** meet the criteria. In conclusion, my question is

- Why doesn't the auxiliary **will** qualify as future tense?

Comment: The point is that "will" is an auxiliary of mood, not tense

Comment: @BillJ If the auxiliary **will** is not for _Tense_, exactly when is _Tense_ marked by auxiliaries? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The perfect tense is marked by the perfect auxiliary "have".

Comment: @BillJ Oh, that clearly holds.

Comment: @BillJ Is it safe to think that, other than the perfect tense, _Tense_ is marked only by verb inflection?

Comment: @Il-seobBae Just so you know, a lot of people would dispute calling the perfect a tense, even ignoring the inflections/auxiliary debate. That is because it doesn't directly refer to a time but instead marks an earlier time to the main tense. So some people call it "secondary tense".

Comment: @Il-seob BaeYes: English has two tense systems. A primary system marked by inflection and a secondary one marked by the perfect auxiliary "have".

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you for pointing out. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @BillJ So, how many tenses are there in English? - because this is one point that I cannot understand from the CamGEL account. (Although I completely understand *will* not indicating a separate tense. And I haven't revisited this recently)

Comment: @BillJ What's H&P?

Comment: H&P = Huddleston & Pullum, the lead authors of The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language (CGEL).

Answer (score 5):

The author seems inconsistent to me.

I am someone who says that English doesn't have a future tense, but that is because I limit what is counted as 'tense' to what is morphologically marked (i.e., by verb inflection.)

But if you're going to include auxiliaries in the tense system, then *will* would surely qualify.

I can think of only one way for what you've quoted to not be inconsistent: if they meant that a language can mark tense either by verb inflection *or* auxiliaries, but *not both*. If that is what they meant, then because English clearly does mark the past tense morphologically, *will* would be excluded. But if that is what they meant they could have explained it rather more clearly!

Comment: I strongly agree with you. I also think that it's logical to confine 'tense' to be the one that's marked only by verb inflection.

Comment: No, "will" is a marker of mood, not tense; that is the crucial point.

Comment: @BillJ Just out of curiousity, is **will** ever used for _Tense_?

Comment: @BillJ *will* can be a marker of mood, in sentences like "I should do it" vs "I will do it", in which case the *will* is usually stressed. But when unstressed in current English it's pretty much a straight temporal marker. If it's contracted then it might always be a straight temporal marker? I'm not sure.

Comment: Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has two tenses: present and preterite. Semantically, it is used to make reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe) but also for expressing volition (as in "I keep telling my son to get his hair cut, but he won't; so I've told him he has to".

Comment: The [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will) definition of **will** makes it clear that some believe that _will_ may be on occasion purely a marker of a future event:  << _will_ also _'ll_: used to talk about what is going to happen in the future, especially things that you are certain about or things that are planned>>.  Verb inflection _has_ to be the key diagnostic for 'future tense' for those holding that there isn't a future tense in English.

Comment: ... As [John Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html) has written, 'But English is almost uninflected,
unlike Latin, and there are really only two inflectional tenses,
on the Latin model, left: present (am/are/is, go(es), walk(s), etc.)
and past [purists may prefer "aorist"] (was/were, went, walked, etc.).' // This viewpoint would render 'Tense. A system marked by ... auxiliaries' unacceptable (as curiousdannii essentially points out).

Comment: The perfect auxiliary "have" (in combination with a following past participle) locates a situation in past time just as much as the preterite does. The inflectional preterite and analytic perfect have a great deal in common, and hence some grammars treat the latter as a tense, not an aspect. And inflection is common throughout all English systems.

Answer (score 0):

Tense is the **form of a verb** to show the **time of action** of the verb.

*According to modern grammar, *there is no future tense in English*.*

For example, in the sentence *"He will work"*, the verb *'work'* is in the base form, i.e., in the present tense; but *future time* is expressed with the help of the the auxiliary verb *'will'*.

Actually, different tense-forms can express future time :

*'He will do this work.'

*'Our principal retires next year.'*

*'We are going to New York next week.'*

*'He is very ill; I'm afraid he is going to die.'*

*I'll come as soon as I have finished writing the letter.'*

*'It is high time we started.'*