# Do native speakers know the tenses?

Tags: tenses

Present simple, past continuous, future perfect, present perfect continuous etc.
These terms are used when English is taught to foreigners. All of them are from quite a neat chart 3×4 of tenses, which are studied thoroughly and separately, and then in speech.
I was wondering if native speakers students who study English use the same terms and approach. I got this idea after I'd read the book of English grammar, by British for the British. It is quite old, and maybe the approach is outdated too. It said there were two tenses, present and past. All the rest were just syntactical constructions for detailed meanings.

Comment: Personal experience (native Br.E speaker): I was taught and learnt far more about tenses when learning _French_ as a foreign language than I did when learning English.

Comment: Native speakers may not know the names you know (or they may have been taught a different set of names) but they know how to use them properly, usually.

Comment: Aren't all tenses syntactical constructions for detailed meanings?

Comment: Even with native speakers, teaching begins with "Present Tense" and "Past Tense". It depends on how far the student continues to learn that the further nuances are gradually introduced. I still keep wondering if there are tenses that I do not know of.  https://www.primebookonline.com/product/complete-list-of-tenses-and-verb-forms

Comment: @Xanne I seriously doubt it. No offense, though.

Comment: I think there's **a good reason why** the "rest" are called "aspects" rather than tenses.

Comment: This topic always makes me tense.  (Partly because the "official" terminology keeps changing.)

Comment: As a native speaker, I took many "English classes" in my time. That said, in middle and high school, our grammar was corrected but we were ***not taught*** tenses in the way an English language learner is taught tenses. Also, we don't do grammar exercises. We write essays and then our essays are corrected for usage and grammar. This will include proper tense sequences, for example, in the corrections.

Comment: It is true that here in ELU we sometimes see questions using terminology from ESL: terminology never taught to or learned by native English speakers.

Comment: That's because native speakers just need a few  adjustments in their writing as they don't need to learn tenses as they already know them, as it were.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many tenses are there in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english)

Comment: I am surprised by the lack of consistency in flagging questions on this site. There is a question here, but it is not a direct question. Being taught English from another language would of course be different than learning it as your primary language. That is true of any language, since you have to engage in translatable values, meanings and structures. The whole purpose of language communication is to relate abstractions as tangibles.

Comment: I've read the comments. Thank you all. We clearly have different ways of teaching the language. In our schools it's mostly about grammar. And students learn all terminology needed for analysis of the language. And yes, it does differ from what foreigners learn when they study it.

Comment: You HAVE heard of a tense called Future Continuous-in-the-Past, haven't you? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Native speakers of English, or really any language, know how to *use* their verbs better than anybody else (and if they make 'mistakes', they make the right mistakes).

But you are really asking about conscious knowledge of their own language and the educated vocabulary used to describe it.

I can't say for other cultures, but in the US schooling system, there is some explanation of grammar with those terms you used in late elementary/early secondary school. But it is not emphasized or repeated later. As mentioned in a comment, most Americans learn more about grammar (and English grammar) when learning grammar of a foreign language.

As to you particular mention about two tenses, that's actually [a bit of a terminological controversy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429932/is-it-true-that-english-has-no-future-tense), where most people informally think of English as having three, but they just would understand the formal vocabulary for tense as meaning English only has two *inflected* tenses (future and aspect are all periphrastic/modal/etc).

I distinctly remember in middle school (early secondary) some older student mentioning that they just learned about the future perfect in English, eg "I will have left for the store by the time you return", and thinking, wow, that must be some university level stuff. But it was never eventually mentioned to me in any English class (almost entirely devoted to literature and writing). And also eventually, I just learned how to do it naturally despite its rarity.

There are so many things in your native language that as a native you are just not aware of, but for non-native learners, an explicit rule makes things so much easier. Which preposition goes with a verb, [the order of adjective roles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order), which article goes with a noun, the native speaker has *no idea* how to describe these, they just do it correctly without a thought.

To your title question, sure, *most* native speakers know the tenses past and present, they've heard things like 'present perfect continuous' but probably don't know exactly what it means, searching hard and failing from their memory of early grade school English.

Of course, ELU denizens, a very particular bunch, might track you down and forcibly explain [every nuance of tense and aspect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another) to you.

Comment: In 7th grade, one of our exercises was to choose an action verb and write out a semi-comprehensive matrix of English conjugation encompassing all the tenses and aspects we had learned to date (*I draw, you draw, he/she/it draws,* etc.). The explicitly stated purpose of it was to prepare us for foreign language classes, not to improve our understanding of English in any way.

Comment: +1, but even within the U.S. there's a lot of variation from school to school and decade to decade. I don't think we ever "officially" learned any name for the progressive/continuous aspect at my school, but we did learn eight named parts of speech, five named uses of nouns, three named types of "verbals", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Native speakers of English learn to use variations in tenses for past, present and future. They are taught as **'Participles'**. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Participles.htm  *If you read the top of the page, only past and present are mentioned. At the bottom of the page, future is added into their examples.*